# Z transform of $x[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c^n * \delta [k-2n] \:; a<0 $

Tags: z-transform

I would want to ask what is the z-transform of this signal x[k]:

$$x[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c^n * \delta [k-2n] \:; c<0 $$

I know that I have to use the geometric series but I really don't know where to even start because of that sum over $n$.

$$X(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c^n * \delta [k-2n])*Z^{-k} $$

The z-transform of $\delta [k-k_0]$ is $Z^{-k_0}$. But what is going on with the sum form n=0?

EDIT: Could it be:

$$X(z)=1+cZ^{-2}+c^2Z^{-4}+c^3Z^{-6}+.....    $$

which makes

$$X(z)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(cZ^{-2})^m = \frac {1}{1-c*Z^{-2}} \:;|cZ^{-2}|<1  $$

Edit2: [image]

Comment: Apparently your $\delta$ stands for Kronecker delta function. That simply imposes $k=2n$ and collapses the sun over $k$. The remaining series is a geometric one.

Comment: @lcv Thank you! :) Indeed, $\delta$ stands for the Kronecker delta function. Did I understand you correctly in my second edit in terms of the calculation (picture)?

Comment: There are two issues you should check. 1) is yours a one-sided or double-sided Z transform? 2) note that $k$ is an integer.